# Angular-material limit width in md-select multiple

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

I have an md-select that after selecting multiple items, the width does not respect the 100% width limit. Here's an example:

Problem: [problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqeFG.png)

```js
/* global angular */
angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);

    angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        
        $scope.fruits = [
            'apple',
            'banana',
            'orange',
            'mango',
            'kiwi',
            'pineapple',
            'lemon',
            'blueberry',
            'strawberry'];
    });
```

```css
/* custom css */
    .no-padding {
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
      }
```

```html
<!- html pages -!>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.9/angular-animate.js"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">

      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="input-group">
        <md-select class="form-control no-padding" ng-model="t" aria-label="t" multiple>
          <md-option ng-value="opt" ng-repeat="opt in fruits">{{opt}}</md-option>
        </md-select>

        <a class="input-group-addon btn btn-md">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
         </a>
         
        </div>
       </div>
     
       <div class="col-xs-4"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
       </div>
       
     </div>
```

The problem only occurs when the user selects 'md-select' items, see the example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues appears to be do to a conflict between bootstrap's input-group which uses table styling and Angular Material which does not. I would recommend using md-input-container instead.

```js
/* global angular */
angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);

angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.fruits = [
    'apple',
    'banana',
    'orange',
    'mango',
    'kiwi',
    'pineapple',
    'lemon',
    'blueberry',
    'strawberry'
  ];
});
```

```css
/* custom css */

.no-padding {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!- html pages -!>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs>
      <md-select class="form-control no-padding" ng-model="t" aria-label="t" multiple>
        <md-option ng-value="opt" ng-repeat="opt in fruits">{{opt}}</md-option>
      </md-select>

      <md-icon><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></md-icon>

    </md-input-container>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="test input">
    </md-input-container>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, really with the <md-input-container> it behaves correctly, will I just look different from the bootstrap, any suggestion to leave the <md-icon> similar to this bootstrap input-group? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Comment: Not really, outside of fiddling with your CSS. The other option is to just not use the ng-material form component and stick with the bootstrap version.

Comment: Can you mark this as solved, or is there anything else I can help with?

Comment: I would like to have another option, there are many components this way on my screen, it got weird the 'md-icon' in that way. Any suggestion changing for for button there on the right?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you earlier. I don't know of another way other than not using the md-select. I have mixed Bootstrap and Angular Material before, but try not to mix them too closely or you get weird behaviors.